# JMeter OS Process Sampler executing delete all files with wildcard in MAC

Tags: jmeter

I have some file in my directory like:

```
request_1.txt
request_2.txt
request_11.txt
request_12.txt
response_1.txt
response_2.txt
response_11.txt
response_12.txt
```

I would like to delete these files before executing the JMeter scenario. I'm using OS Process Sampler and config:

- Command: `rm`
- Working directory: `path/to/my/directory/`
- Command parameters: `re*.txt`

**It didn't work**. Nothing is deleted.

I tried to run the command `rm re*.txt` in the **`terminal`** then it works well, all files was deleted as my expected.

`Note:` If I change the Command parameters to specific file as `request_1.txt`. This file will be deleted normally.

So what am I doing wrong while using the wildcard in OS Process Sampler? Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `rm` command doesn't know anything about wildcards. Wildcards is one of the features of [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), most likely you're using [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))

So in order to fix your issue you should be calling [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) instead of [rm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm)

Example configuration:

[image: OS Process Sampler]

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article to get more information on kicking off external processes from JMeter test scripts.

Comment: How can I say thanks to you, @Dmitri T? Your answer solved my problem. But I don't familiar with Unix shell, also Bash, so can you tell me what is parameter `-c`, what does it mean?

Comment: **-c string**
If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.